# Why do I need to set layout_height when maxHeight and minHeight are set

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, autosize

I want the height of my `TextView` to auto-size its `layout_height` when max/min text size is hit.

**Problem**: In order to auto-size my text, I am forced to add a `layout_height`. There are cases where the text is one or two words and cases where there are many words. When there are only one or two words my text hits the `autoSizeMaxTextSize` but the `layout_height` remains at `200dp` and then my view looks like there is a big space between my `TextView` (the title) and the lower view (the body) because I set a static height for `layout_height`. When I have less text I do not want my `TextView`'s height to take up the full `200dp` but to scale down to the minHeight instead.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLength="70"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="@{title.trim()}"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="42sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

I have tried using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in conjunction with `android:minHeight="100dp"` and `android:maxHeight="200dp"` and the auto text resizing. The result was to wrap content with no text resizing and no maxHeight.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Because when the view's parent lays it out and figures out how much space to give it, it doesn't know about those fields.  It only knows about the layout_ fields.  It sizes it completely based on that and on the layout rules of the parent.  min and max text size is only used by the view itself when deciding what font size to use.

Ah, you asked a different question in the body.  If you want the size of the text view to change based on length of text, use wrap_content for height.  To put a max height, put it inside a view with layout_height 200, or use contraint rules in a ConstraintLayout to set a max height.

Comment: I have tried using `layout_height="wrap_content"` in conjunction with `android:minHeight="100dp"` and `android:maxHeight="200dp"` and the auto text resizing. The result was to wrap content with no text resizing and no maxHeight.